# Mathematica does not fully simplify units

Tags: units

I use the Quantity function in Mathematica to simplify and check units. Sometimes I cannot get Mathematica to simplify units. What I am doing wrong?

For example, find units of thermal diffusivity:

```
k = Quantity["W/(m K)"]
ρ = Quantity["Kg / m^3"]
Subscript[c, p] = Quantity["kJ / (kg K)"]

k/(ρ Subscript[c, p])
```

Convert to SI base:

```
UnitConvert[k/(ρ Subscript[c, p]), "SI"]
```

The output is:
("Kelvins" ("Meters")^2 "Watts")/("KelvinsDifference" "Kilojoules")

Why will it not simplify the units to $m^2/s$?

Comment: Note that a workaround is `k = Quantity["W/m 1/K"]`

Comment: Note that you need to use `UnitConvert[k/(\[Rho] Subscript[c, p]), "m^2/s"]` to get the result you want, a single `UnitSimplify[]` reduces it to volt/Tesla.